# How to sort files starting with _ in python

Tags: python

I have files in one directory.

The filenames are weird, some of it starts with _, while others start with alphabet.

```
    _weight.txt
     color.txt
    _height.txt
```

I am looking for a way to sort it alphabetically in python. I know how to sort it alphabetically but doesn't have idea about files starting with special characters such as _.

can anybody help?

so according to replies, following is my code:

```
toolpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
directory = os.listdir(toolpath)
for files in directory:
    if files.endswith(".html")
       sorted(files, key=lambda x:x.lstrip("_").lower())
       htmlfile.write('<a href='+files+'>'+files+'</a><br>\n')
```

at one place where I had to sort txt files, it worked. while in above code still it doesn't print in alphabetical order. 
I have one more question, filename is for example color.html, thus my code writes to html the filename color.html.
How can I write just color to html page rather than color.html?

Comment: What type of sorting algorithm are you using? E.G. bubble, quicksort, radix, etc? You would likely need to decide how you want those items sorted, and then implement a rule in the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you want to ignore the `_`, you can lstrip the `_` in the key to sorted/.sort to remove any leading underscores:

```
words = ["_weight.txt","color.txt","_height.txt"]

print(sorted(words, key=lambda x: x.lstrip("_")))
['color.txt', '_height.txt', '_weight.txt']
```

Not sure what you are sorting as the strangely named `files` is actual a string but if you want to find all the html files in the `directory` and sort then you can use glob and sort the list returned by glob:

```
from glob import glob
toolpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
directory = os.listdir(os.path.join(toolpath,"*.html"))
directory.sort( key=lambda x: x.lstrip("_")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I also have some file names starting with capital letter like Perimeter.txt etc. I tried your code, but it doesn't sort.

Comment: Just add .lower `x.lstrip("_").lower()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked at one place. while at other place, it is not working. I have updated the post with my code. can you tell me where am I getting wrong?

Comment: You  realise sorted creates a new list? If you want an inplace sort use .sort, `files.sort( key=lambda x: x.lstrip("_")))`

Comment: it is throwing me attribute error. 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: I presumed files was a list,, why are you calling sorted on the filename? Are you trying to filter the files in a directory to only keep the html files and then sort those?

Comment: no. actually source is the directory which contains all files.

Comment: @geek_xed, I added more code, if that is not what you want I am lost as there are no other lists in your code

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the `_` in a `key`

```
>>> sorted(filelist, key=lambda x: x[1:] if x.startswith('_') else x)
```